# Using PHP cURL to get some text from website and store in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, curl, web-scraping, php-curl

I have been looking around for a while to make this work but seems that I can't do it by myself. I am using cURL to get some informations from an website and store those infos on MySQL database. What I have right now is following code :

```
$target_url = "[http:\[//\]iliria98\[.\]com][1]"; //delete [ and ] to get the url correctly
$userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';

// make the cURL request to $target_url
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
$html= curl_exec($ch);
if (!$html) {
    echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
    echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
    exit;
}

// parse the html into a DOMDocument
$document = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$document->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
$selector = new DOMXPath($document);
//$anchors = $selector->query('//div[@class="single"]/div[2]');
$anchors = $selector->query('//div[@class="single"]/div');
foreach($anchors as $div) { 
    $text = $div->nodeValue;

    $valuta_arr=explode(',', $text);
    var_dump($valuta_arr);
    echo $text;
}
```

And, the output is not a correct one, since it gets all te currency codes from the website, but the currency values are only from the first rows, from USD.
What I want is to get the values from the html table on the url specified and to insert those values in the database for every currency, where the database table looks like this:

```
id
currency
sell
buy
date
```

I didn't get till the mysql insert code since I have been struggling for 3 days to firstly get the informations fro that website.
Hope that someone can help me on this.
Thank you to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you will try to get this page from the console by `curl http://iliria98.com` you will find, that this widget is filled by js-script:

```
$('div#usd1').append('<div style="position: absolute; background: transparent; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 9999;"></div>')
$(".kursiweb .single").eq(0).find("div").eq(1).html("114<sup>.20</sup>");  $(".kursiweb .single").eq(0).find("div").eq(2).html("116");
```

and etc...

So, you can get needed data only from this script in source HTML you get from curl, not from the DOM document, just because curl didn't have any JS engine.

Another way you can go - to use something like [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't go till the end of the source code to see the script in there. Sorry for that. Regarding your suggestion, I don't have any experience with javascript. Would you help me on this to make it work?
Thank you!

Comment: Have tried many ways that i have found around here but seems that nothing works for me. Surely, I don't know how to do it. Any help, please?

Comment: @Kleidi ok, you can also try something like [php-webdriver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver)

Comment: Thank you. It is too coplicated for me. The cURL query was a little bit more understandable for me but i can't make it work so I will let it go. Thank you!

Comment: @Kleidi glad to be helpful, if this answer was helpful you can mark it as accepted. Than, yeap, not all things can be scraped from the internet just by a simple curl... Like in this example, the code generated by the javascript can't be scraped this way. You just need something I suggested you below.